# MySQL using a OR in select to locate a contact in column

Tags: mysql

I'm using this MySQL query to locate a contact that is in either a column called Contact1Name or Contact2Name

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (Contact1Name='XYZ' OR Contact2Name='XYZ')
```

This works well, the only problem is then I have to do additional validation to determine which contact the result is, Contact1 or Contact2, is there a MySQL way to do this where possibly it only returns the correct contact column?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Contact1Name='XYZ'
            THEN some_column1
            ELSE some_column2
            END AS some_column
FROM contacts 
WHERE 'XYZ' IN (Contact1Name, Contact2Name)
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work with the THEN some_column1 ELSE some_column2 END AS some_column not sure exactly what these lines are supposed to do. If I remove these lines then it returns correct result just like my original using the OR but still doesnt solve problem of showing the column name I want. basically I want to know which column the result matches.

Comment: @JohnRoberts *not sure exactly what these lines are supposed to do.* I don't know what columns values must be taken. An example in the question text (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows, with desired output) may help to give more detailed answer.